# java itextpdf 5.5.6 custom font not displaying properly

Tags: java, fonts, itext

I am using ITextPdf (5.5.6) with my java + android web application to generate pdf.I wanted to view the contents in Gotham Light font. Therefore I have downloaded a Gotham Light .ttf file and created a font as follows.
In my generated pdf it looks like it is the good font but it is bolder.

The version that i am using of iText does support Gotham Ligh ?

The code that i am using:

```
    Template t = ve.getTemplate(contratXHTML, "UTF-8");
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    t.merge(context, writer);
    String body = writer.toString();
    writer.close(); 

    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(absolutePathContratPDF);

    renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Gotham Light_0.ttf",BaseFont.EMBEDDED);     
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(body);
    renderer.layout();      

    renderer.createPDF(os);
    os.close();
    FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File(pathTemporalDirectory));
    return body;
```

Please can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck with a similar problem,

The problem was not with the font you add, but the CSS/style used to body (HTML body) you want to print in PDF.

Please specify the font-family correctly. In my case, I used Arial font along with

> font-family: Arial; in

and my font did not work with  tag.
So, changing it to

> font-family: sans-serif;

resolved the issue.

In few cases, you might need to define

> font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

Reference : https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000095wDIAQ